# Get entire X509 certificate chain using OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to get the entire certificate chain for a given domain using the following code (error checking removed for brevity):

```
int myFunction() {
    for (int i = 0; i < CERTIFICATE_CHAIN_MAXIMUM; i++) {
        certificateChain[i] = NULL;
    }
    numberOfCerts = 0;

    OPENSSL_init();
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
    ERR_load_SSL_strings();

    SSL_CTX * ctx = NULL;
    BIO * web = NULL;
    SSL * ssl = NULL;

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());

    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, CERTIFICATE_CHAIN_MAXIMUM);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, verify_callback);
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION);

    web = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);

    BIO_set_conn_hostname(web, host) // host defined elasewhere
    BIO_get_ssl(web, &ssl);

    const char* const PREFERRED_CIPHERS = "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4";
    SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, PREFERRED_CIPHERS)

    SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, [URL.host UTF8String])
    BIO_do_connect(web)
    BIO_do_handshake(web)
}

int verify_callback(int preverify, X509_STORE_CTX* x509_ctx)
{
    STACK_OF(X509) * certs = X509_STORE_CTX_get1_chain(x509_ctx);
    X509 * cert;
    for (int i = 0, count = sk_X509_num(certs); i < count; i++) {
        if (i < CERTIFICATE_CHAIN_MAXIMUM) {
            cert = sk_X509_value(certs, i);
            if (cert != NULL) {
                certificateChain[i] = cert;
                numberOfCerts ++;
            }
        } else {
            printf("Certificate chain maximum exceeded.");
        }
    }

    return preverify;
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that I'm only getting the client certificate, and intermediate CA(s), but not the root CA.

For example, the certificate chain for `github.com` is:

```
DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
  > github.com
```

But with my code, I only end up with:

```
DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
> github.com
```

I'm assuming that the issue is that I have to recursively get the parent certificate for each certificate, however I'm unsure about how to do this and struggle to find anything helpful in terms of documentation.

Comment: The verify_callback is called for each certificate in the trust chain, including the root certificate. Which mean that you don't need to traverse the chain yourself but instead only look at `X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert` for each call of the function. And of course you need to setup the location of the trust store where it should find the root certificate. See the example code in [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html).

Comment: The CA Root is not sent in a well configured server. The client must already have it and trust it. Otherwise, a bad guy could intercept the connection and swap-in his own chain. Also see [TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki. It prints all issuers and subjects in the chain.

Comment: In my current code, my verify_callback is only called once for github with a depth of 1. Because this code is running in an iOS app, verification is done outside of the scope of OpenSSL (though Apple's Security library) so I don't need to do any verification with openssl.